# Finding Weird Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, data-structures

A weird number is a number that the sum of proper divisors is greater than the number itself and no subset of proper divisors sum to that number.

Examples:

> 70 is a weird number because its proper divisors (1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 14, and 35) sum to 74, which is greater than 70, and no combination of these numbers sum to 70.

> 18 is not a weird number because its proper divisors (1, 2, 3, 6, 9) sum to 21, which is greater than 18, but 3, 6, and 9 sum to 18.

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that gets this weird number from `1 to 100`

I am struggling at condition #2 **no subset of proper divisors sum to that number.**

**UPDATE :** I could get this much logic for condition #2

```
 // assuming we put all the divisiors in an array.
36 => [1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18]

// we take first two numbers
[1,2] 
// are they less than 36?
yes

arr.forEach(n,idx){
  let k = arr[idx] + arr[idx+1]
  if(k<36){
    let sum = 0
    sum = k + arr[idx+2]
  }
}
```

I could figure the logic behind it but I couldn't solve it.

```js
function magicNum(){
  let arr = []
  for(let i =0;i<=100;i++){
    arr.push(i)
  }
  arr.forEach(n=>{
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 1 ; i<n ; i++){
    if(n%i===0){
      sum+=i
      }
    }
  if(sum > n){
      console.log(n) // I could get the first condition
    }
  })
}

magicNum()
```

Comment: you need to check **every** subset. To do that you need first to create an array of all proper divisors and then try every combination of them to see if they equal the number itself.

Comment: I have done the exact logic in the whiteboard but I couldn't translate that into code @user1984

Comment: btw, why has 18 a divisor of 4?

Comment: @NinaScholz Fixed

Answer (score 3):

You could check each possible combination by using a bitmask for the values.

```js
const
    check = (value, array) => {
        let n = 1 << array.length;
        while (n--) {
            if (value === array.reduce((s, v, i) => s + v * !!(1 << i & n), 0)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

console.log(check(18, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]));
console.log(check(70, [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 14, 35]));
```

Comment: this is great answer thank you but it would be good if you could explain the ```s,v,i, << , n```

Comment: `s` is the accumulator of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), `v` is the acutal value and `i` the actual index. `n` is calculated with [left shift <<](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift) with the length of the array. by using any decremeenting value, the bits of the number arecompared to the index value and if set, it add `v` to the sum.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Updated to check abundancy.

I would do this with three reusable functions.  `divisors` lists all the divisors of a number, `powerset` lists all the subsets (as arrays) of a set (also given as an array), and `sum` adds a list of numbers.

Then we can combine them by taking the divisors, removing the final one (the original number), and then taking all subsets of that set, and checking whether any of these subsets sums to the initial number.  It would look like this:

```js
const divisors = (n, i = 1, inc = [], dec = []) =>
  i * i > n 
    ? [...inc, ...dec .reverse ()]
  : n % i == 0 
    ? divisors (n, i + 1, [...inc, i], i * i == n ? dec : [...dec, n / i])
  : divisors (n, i + 1, inc, dec)

const powerset = ([x, ...xs]) =>
  x == undefined
    ? [[]]
    : powerset (xs) .flatMap (ss => [ss, [x, ...ss]])
    
const sum = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const weirdNumber = (n) => { 
  const factors = divisors (n) 
  return sum (factors) > 2 * n &&
         ! powerset (factors .slice (0, -1)) .some (ss => sum (ss) == n)
}

console .log (weirdNumber (70))
console .log (weirdNumber (18))
```

`sum` is trivial, and `powerset` is a simple enough recursion.  `divisors` is a little more tricky, as we simultaneously accumulate the increasing small divisors and the decreasing large one, merging them together at the end.  Thus when checking `divisors (72)` we will have these values in the recursive steps:

| i | inc | dec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [1] | [72] |
| 2 | [1, 2] | [72, 36] |
| 3 | [1, 2, 3] | [72, 36, 24] |
| 4 | [1, 2, 3, 4] | [72, 36, 24, 18] |
| 5 | [1, 2, 3, 4] | [72, 36, 24, 18] |
| 6 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] | [72, 36, 24, 18, 12] |
| 7 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] | [72, 36, 24, 18, 12] |
| 8 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8] | [72, 36, 24, 18, 12, 9] |

and then, because `9 * 9` is greater than `72`, we are done and reverse `dec` and return its concatenation with `inc`.

The special processing `i * i == n ? ...` is to handle the case where the number is a perfect square.  In `divisors (49)` for instance, we wouldn't want to include `7` in both `inc` and `dec`.

The main function is simple enough, using `some` to test if any subset has a matching sum, and negating the result.

Note that `divisors`, `powerset`, and `sum` are all reusable functions.  Only `weirdNumber` is specific to this problem.

Also note that this is quite inefficient.  We could definitely find a more efficient way to check for the key pattern, as this will keep summing even when we're already too large.  If we want to test, say, `360`, we need to find all `223` subsets of its `23` proper factors and sum each of them.  We could certainly find improvements to the speed there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function magicNum(){
  function checkSubsets(idx, arr, curr, target) {
    if (curr === target) return true

    for (let i = idx; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (checkSubsets(i+1, arr, curr+arr[i], target)) return true
    }
    return false
  }
  let arr = []
  for(let i =0;i<=100;i++){
    arr.push(i)
  }
  arr.forEach(n=>{
  const divisors = []
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 1 ; i<n ; i++){
    if(n%i===0){
      divisors.push(i)
      sum += i
      }
    }
  if(sum > n){
      console.log(n) // I could get the first condition
    }
  if (checkSubsets(0, divisors, 0, n)) {
    console.log("One of the subsets of " + n + "equals " + n)
  }
  })
}

magicNum()
```

I don't know much JavaScript, so sorry if this is not very clean. The bulk of the subset checking algorithm is in `checkSubsets`.

```js
  function checkSubsets(idx, arr, curr, target) {
    if (curr === target) return true

    for (let i = idx; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (checkSubsets(i+1, arr, curr+arr[i], target)) return true
    }
    return false
  }
```

As you can see, it takes the index of the current item `idx`, the array of all proper divisors `arr`, the sum of the current subset `curr`, and the `target` which is the `n` we are currently examining.

It the recursively calls itself by incrementing the index by one and adding the current item to the current total sum. If it finds `curr == target` it returns `true`. After checking all combinations, if it doesn't find anything, it returns false.

To make sure the number is weird, you need to make a test like follows:

```js
if (sum <= n && !checkSubsets(0, divisors, 0, n) {
  console.log(n + " is weired, because the sum of its proper divisors was smaller or equal to itself and no subset of its divisors was equal to it")... }
```

Comment: How can I get the weird numbers then?

Comment: To get the weird numbers both those conditions must be false. Meaning `sum > n` and `checkSubsets...` both must return false for `n` to be weird. @MohammedAlhawamdeh

Comment: Look at the edit I added to the end of my answer @MohammedAlhawamdeh

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeirdNumber.html) stated:

> A "weird number" is a number that is abundant (i.e., the sum of proper divisors is greater than the number) without being pseudoperfect (i.e., no subset of the proper divisors sums to the number itself). The pseudoperfect part of the definition means that finding weird numbers is a case of the subset sum problem.

My code below doesn't take pseudoperfect subsets into mind.

How I went about to solve this:

- 1 will always be added: in code, `sum` starts on 1.
- you only need to loop the lower half the possibly weird number, and instead add both the divider and the result to the sum: in code, will only loop to `half`.
- you need to keep track if the number have already been added, because 5 * 14 is lower than (70/2=) 35 and will be calculated twice (5+14, 14+5) in the lower part of the possibly weird number: in code, `addedNumbers` keeps track on that.

You could write this in a shorter way, but I prefer to have readable code.

```js
function isWeird(number) {
  let half = parseInt(number / 2) - 1,
      sum = 1,
      evenNumber = -1,
      addedNumbers = new Set();
  
  for (let divider = sum+1; divider < half; divider++) {
    evenNumber = parseInt(number/divider);
    
    if (!addedNumbers.has(divider) && number / divider == evenNumber) {
      sum += divider + evenNumber;
      addedNumbers.add(divider);
      addedNumbers.add(evenNumber);
    }
  }
  
  let isWeird = sum > number;
  
  return {number, sum, isWeird}; 
}


let value = 70;

console.log(isWeird(value));

value = 10;

console.log(isWeird(value));
```